# How to apply dynamic style to a column, in which there are numeric type values ​and I want to apply colors depending on ranges of values

Tags: angular, typescript

Good afternoon, I have an angular data table and one of its column is numerical values, in which I want to apply a ngStyle to change the presentation color, but I want to do this through a range of values, as follows:

If the value is between 100 and 90, I want to have the style color: red.

If the value is between 90 and 70 I want it to be shown with color: orange

If the value is between 70 and 60, I want it to be shown with color: yellow

For all other values, color: blue

I have used ngStyle simply for true or false conditionals, but in this case I don't know how to apply it.

The column to which I want to apply this condition is **U.IN**[image]

```
  <div [hidden]="dataSource.loading$ | async">
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
                                                  <!-- Columna ID -->
            <!-- <ng-container matColumnDef="id_interface">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef matTooltip="ID Interface" matTooltipPosition="above">ID</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.id_interface}}</td>
            </ng-container> -->
                                                <!-- Columna Equipo Origen -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="EquipoOrigen">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef matTooltip="Equipo de Origen" matTooltipPosition="above">Equipo O.</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" >{{element.EquipoOrigen}}</td>
            </ng-container>
                                                  <!-- Columna Puerto Origen -->                  
            <ng-container matColumnDef="PuertoOrigen">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef matTooltip="Puerto de Origen" matTooltipPosition="above">Puerto O.</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.PuertoOrigen}}</td>
            </ng-container>

                                            <!-- columna Equipo Destino -->                  
            <ng-container matColumnDef="EquipoDestino">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef matTooltip="Equipo de Destino. El valor N/A indica NO ASIGNADO" matTooltipPosition="above">Equipo D.</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.EquipoDestino}}</td>
            </ng-container>
                                              <!-- Columna Puerto Destino -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="PuertoDestino">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef matTooltip="Puerto de Destino. El valor N/A indica NO ASIGNADO" matTooltipPosition="above">Puerto D.</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.PuertoDestino}} </td>
            </ng-container>
                                                <!-- Columna Ancho de Banda (bw) Configurado -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="ospf_per">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef matTooltip="Indica el estado OSPF Operativo(Consulta cada 1 minuto el Estatus OSPF en los equipos)" matTooltipPosition="above" >OSPF</th>
              <td class="resaltado"  [ngStyle]="{'color': OSPF[element.ospf_per]==='FULL' ? 'blue' : OSPF[element.ospf_per]==='DOWN' ? 'red':'green'}" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{OSPF[element.ospf_per]}}</td>
            </ng-container>
                                              <!-- Columna Ancho de Banda (bw_ve) Verdadero-->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="bw_ve">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef matTooltip="BW Real expresado en Mbps" matTooltipPosition="above">BW</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.bw_ve | number}}</td>
            </ng-container>
                                            <!-- Columna % Utilizacion IN del puerto  -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="inUtil">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  matTooltip="Porcentaje de utilizacion del puerto IN expresado en %" matTooltipPosition="above">U.IN</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.inUtil | number}} %</td>
            </ng-container>
                                          <!-- Columna Velocidad IN del puerto  -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="speedIn">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef matTooltip="Velocidad de entrada del puerto expresada en Mbps" matTooltipPosition="above">Rate IN</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.speedIn | number}}</td>
            </ng-container>  
                                      <!-- Columna % Utilizacion OUT del puerto  -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="outUtil">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef matTooltip="Porcentaje de utilizacion del puerto OUT expresado en %" matTooltipPosition="above">U.OUT</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.outUtil | number}} %</td>
            </ng-container>
                                         <!-- Columna Velocidad OUT del puerto  -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="speedOut">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef matTooltip="Velocidad de salida del puerto expresada en Mbps" matTooltipPosition="above">Rate OUT</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.speedOut | number}}</td>
            </ng-container>
                                       <!-- Columna N° Ticket Asociado  -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="ticket">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef matTooltip="N° Ticket Asociado a la interface en la gestion de incidencias en REMEDY" matTooltipPosition="above">Ticket</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.ticket}}</td>
            </ng-container>

                                          <!-- Columna Ultima Actualizacion-->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="actualizacion_ospf">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef matTooltip="Indica la hora en la que ocurrio el ultimo cambio de estado en OSPF" matTooltipPosition="above">Cambio OSPF</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.actualizacion_ospf | date:'d/M/yyyy,  h:mm a'}}</td>
            </ng-container>

                                                <!-- Columna Acciones -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Detalles</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">

                        <fa-icon [icon]=icon_view class="btn btn-dark"    (click)="onDetails(element.id_interface)" matTooltip="Ver Detalles" matTooltipPosition="above" ></fa-icon>&nbsp;

                    </td>
                </ng-container>

            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
      </table>
                                                          <!--Paginador -->
            <mat-paginator [pageSize]="10" [length]='dataSource?.dataLength' (page)='loadpaginator()'  [pageSizeOptions]="[5,10,20,50]" #paginator></mat-paginator>  
  </div>  
                                                      <!-- Spinner de Carga -->
  <ng-container *ngIf="dataSource.loading$ | async">
        <mat-spinner class="spinner-container"></mat-spinner> <br>
        <p>Su data esta siendo cargada, por favor espere</p>
  </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply call a function in `ngStyle` and return the desired colors accordingly based on the conditions.

Use `ngStyle` in the HTML

```html
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [ngStyle]="{'color': getColor(element.inUtil)}">{{element.inUtil | number}} %</td>
```

Then in your component create the `getColor` function.

```js
getColor(inUtil) {
    if (inUtil <= 100 && inUtil >= 90)
        return 'red';
    else if (inUtil < 90 && inUtil >= 70)
        return 'orange';
    else if (inUtil < 70 && inUtil >= 60)
        return 'yellow';
    else
        return 'blue';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ngStyle` but i'm not a fan of having inline styles.

I will suggest creating 3 new styles in your `.scss` file (feel free to choose your own class names.

```css
/* component.scss */
.color-red {
  color: red
}

.color-orange {
  color: orange
}

.color-yellow {
  color: yellow
}

.color-blue {
  color: blue
}
```

Then in your component use `[ngClass]`

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="inUtil">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  matTooltip="Porcentaje de utilizacion del puerto IN expresado en %" matTooltipPosition="above">U.IN</th>
  <td 
    mat-cell 
    *matCellDef="let element"
    [ngClass]="{'color-red': element.inUtil >= 90, 'color-orange': element.inUtil >= 70 && element.inUtil < 90}
  >
    {{element.inUtil | number}} %
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

There are multiple ways to use `ngClass`: https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#description